# iOS project private and public dependencies

Tags: ios, git, xcode6

I have a git-managed iOS application (built mostly in Swift, Xcode 6 beta 4) for which I would like to pull some code out into a git subtree. The code for that is all in a “Common” directory. The problem is, that the “Common” code depends on a Cocoapod (ObjectiveRecord, which depends on ObjectiveSugar).

Under these circumstances, what would be the best way to manage these pieces independently? Ideally, I would like to be able to keep my commit history, although I could stand to lose it if it would make things easier.

I have two ideas that seem like they might work, although I do not know how to go about implementing them:

- Have my iOS app depend on a git subtree of the Common code, and that subtree also depend on a subtree of ObjectiveRecord (EDIT: and stop using CocoaPods)
- Have my iOS app depend an a private CocoaPod of my common code, and that CocoaPod also depend on a CocoaPod of ObjectiveRecord.

I would like to be able to make changes to the common code from anywhere and keep the changes everywhere. For instance, if I have the workspace for App1 that has a subtree of Common, and I edit Common from there, I can commit and have App2 pull in the Common changes (and vice versa). Or if I just have the workspace for Common open, edit it there and App1, App2, etc. can all pull in the Common changes — similar to SVN externals.

I have tried this tutorial: http://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I ended up going with the private local CocoaPod option. The only problem I am having now is that in Xcode 6 beta 4, "using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported". Hopefully that will be fixed in beta 5.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please remove the svn tag, I don't see it being relevant here.